# FNAF Bundle "glitch?"

Tags: steam, fnaf-sister-location

So I own the FNaF bundle on Steam. The last game (FNAF: Sister Location) has been added to the bundle some time ago, and it also appeared in my library without me paying a single cent.

Is this intended, or is this some kind of a bug?

Answer (score 2):

From personal experience, I can say that this is most likely not a bug. When I bought the BIT.TRIP bundle before the whole series was available on Steam, the remaining games appeared in my library as soon as they were added to Steam and the bundle, even though they weren't part of it at the time of my purchase.

According to a discussion I read back then (which I can't find right now), bundles seem to work like a kind of season pass - when you buy one, Steam considres you to have paid for the whole series, so you recieve any games that get added to that bundle for free.

I can't say for certain that the same is true for all bundles, but it's definitely not an exceptional case.

Comment: Traditionally on Steam, you don't get games when bundles are updated.

Comment: @Powerlord That may be, but like I said, it did happen to me, and apparently to everyone else who bought that particular bundle. I'm guessing this is something the developer/publisher gets to decide on a case by case basis.

Answer (score -1):

You pad for the bundle. Like any game you don't have to pay for it to be updated. So when Scott added Sister Location to the Bundle, it automatically put it in your library since you've been had the bundle

Answer (score -2):

Its because you can't pay for it again. You payed for the original bundle and cant pay again. Hope i helped!